# Triggering an Google Webapp on form submit

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Webapp which when run shows a HTML message whether the execution has successfully completed or not. My problem is that I want to set up this Webapp as a trigger form a Google form submission.

I can have a normal trigger on form submit BUT that does NOT show the HTML message whether the execution has succeeded. So, I created the Webapp. But I am at a loss as to how trigger this Webapp through the form.

Any help will be appreciated

Madhurjya

Comment: I think it is not possible as of now, what you might try is use that form in an Iframe and thus redirect user to some other page or content. you can also make HTML based form in an webApp that can also work as google form

Comment: I am afraid that this exact setup is not possible. Could you please share a little bit more about what you are trying to achieve in the big picture, as it could possibly be accomplished in another way?